# testing function with axios call in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios, enzyme

I was trying to test a function that makes Axios call and the returned data was being assigned to State of a React component.
Following is the code that I wanted to test

```js
class ViewBooking extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bookingId: "",
      bookingData: [],
      errorMessage: ""
    };
  }

fetchBookingbyID = () => {
    const { bookingId } = this.state;
    axios.get("http://localhost:4000/bookings/" + bookingId)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ bookingData: response.data});
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          errorMessage: "Details of "+bookingId + " is not found!"
        });
      });
  }
}
```

The test case that I have written is given below:

```js
test("Axios GET request : fetchBookingbyID", async () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ViewBooking />);
    var mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
    const mockData2 = {
      id: 1001,
      buffetName: "BBQ Special",
      emailId: "absy@gmail.com"
    };
    mock.onGet("http://localhost:4000/bookings/1001").reply(200, mockData2);
    wrapper.setState({ bookingId: 1001 });
    await wrapper.instance().fetchBookingbyID();
    expect(wrapper.state().bookingData).toEqual(mockData2)
  });
```

Now, this test case always passes.. even if I remove the code written in fetchBookingbyId() method.

Comment: I will suggest u not to test implementation details of ur app, but the behaviour, meaning not to be aware of the fact that there is an api call with axios to fetch the data, but, to test that after the component is rendered, it has a list of items that it's source is the api response.

In that way, your tests are not coupled to a specific implementation.

Comment: In that case, Will I not have to keep the server running always whenever the test cases are fired, to check for the list of items

Comment: It is not related, it is your decision if you want to work against real server, or mock the api responses via some lib such as [Nock](https://github.com/nock/nock), [fetchMock](http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/)